# Accessing blocker.BlockedBy

Tags: rally

Using Rally SDK 2.0, I am customizing the kanban board app.  One of the items I am doing is trying to add who set the story to BLOCKED status.

When debugging it seems ok, but for some reason my blocker.BlockedBy is set to undefined.  I am guessing I need to do something a bit different than this?

**var blocker = this.getRecord().get("Blocker");**

// blocker.BlockedBy is undefined right here
// blocker seems populated, but I am not sure its actually a Blocker object.

I added "Blocker" to the additional fields for the card as well
getAdditionalFetchFields: function () {
 return ['Owner', 'FormattedID', 'Blocked', 'Ready', 'Priority', 'DefectStatus', 'Defects', "PlanEstimate", "LastUpdateDate", "TaskStatus", "**Blocker**"];

In the documentation it says that type Blocker is " non-creatable type", so not sure what this actually means...

Seems like the object coming back from the call has a _type field defining it as "Blocker".

Kinda stuck, I have tried typecasting the result to a Blocker, but still not having much luck.  Just want to get who blocked the story :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `Blocker` as a fetch field, it's only returning a simple ref object that represents the Blocker object. But you can also tell fetch to fetch Blocker fields. So if you add `BlockedBy` as another field to fetch, it will grab that for your Blockers. WSAPI does a little magic here to figure out that you mean `BlockedBy` on the `Blocker` object.

`BlockedBy` is a `User` object, so the easiest way from there to get the user's name is with

```
var blockerName = this.getRecord().get('Blocker').BlockedBy._refObjectName;
```

Comment: Hmm, I would have never tried that :)  Thanks, it works great.

Comment: No prob. And also as for the "non creatable type" bit, that means only the Rally backend can make Blockers. A user can't create a Blocker except indirectly by blocking something.